# cmd: Open a browser when a string is output using docker

Tags: docker, if-statement, batch-file, cmd, while-loop

I'm running a docker command from inside cmd (a .bat script).
The command looks like
`docker run --shm-size=1gb -it --privileged --name test p 8080:8080 -h test thom/test:latest` 
I want to make a loop that waits for a certain string to appear after I invoke this command, or it waits for the port (8080) to be open. The string is "Daemon started!", and when it is output, I want to open a browser:

```
explorer "http://localhost:8080"
```

I'm struggling to make a while loop in batch though without restarting the docker command. This is what I have so far.

```
:loop
timeout /t 5
(docker run --shm-size=1gb -it --privileged --name test p 8080:8080 -h test thom/test:latest | find "proxy Daemon started!")  > nul 2>&1
if find "proxy Daemon started!" goto loop
echo I can go!
explorer "http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findstr` and the resulting `errorlevel` to perform the actions accodringly, you can also use conditional operators `&&` and `||` as seen in the second example:

```
@echo off
:loop
timeout /t 5
(docker run --shm-size=1gb -it --privileged --name test p 8080:8080 -h test thom/test:latest | findstr /R "proxy.*Daemon.*started")>nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto :loop
echo I can go!
explorer "http://localhost:8080"
```

or Confitional operator usage:

```
:loop
timeout /t 5
(docker run --shm-size=1gb -it --privileged --name test p 8080:8080 -h test thom/test:latest | findstr /R "proxy.*Daemon.*started")>nul 2>&1 && explorer "http://localhost:8080" || goto :loop
```